# Unzip only selected file types on Windows using R

Tags: r, list, unzip

I have a load of .zip files which I've been unzipping using an `R` loop.  This is extraordinarily slow. I actually only want .mp3 and .jpg files unzipped. Is there a way to just unzip those files? I know I can use the `files` argument but I'm not sure how I put it all together. This is where I'm at so far:

```
a <- list.files('P:\\\\',pattern='.zip',full.names=T,recursive=T, include.dirs=T)

#create empty list to store file names
z.files <- c()
#fill that list with the files inside the .zips
for(i in 1:length(a)){
  z <- a[[i]]
  z.files <- c(z.files,try(unzip(z,list=T))) #list all the files rather than unzipping
}

#just list the files ending mp3/jpg
lapply(z.files, function(X) X[grepl("\\.(?:jpg|mp3)$", X)])

#unzip all of the zips
for(i in 1:length(a)){
  z <- a[[i]]
  try(unzip(z))
}
```

Comment: `grepl("\\.(?:jpg|mp3)$", X)`

Comment: Should've been clearer - I've amended to that (thanks!) but it's getting from there to just unzipping the files in that list that's confusing me

Comment: Well, once you have the list of files you want, can't you just do `unzip(zipfilepath, files=list_of_files)` ?

Comment: Only if I can 'align' the list of zips with the list of files, then I could do something like:
unzip(a[[1]],files=mus.pic.files[[1]])
But even without getting rid of the empty entries (i.e. zips with no mp3 or jpg in them, from the 'files' bit e.g. using `mus.pic.files[lapply(mus.pic.files,length)>0]`) they don't seem to align. Of course it would also be preferable not to even try such .zips